# GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I found similar questions about this error but I can't make it work

I'm working on a java 8, spring 2.6.4 and a MySQL database

I'm trying to do a DELETE native query using JPA and I'm getting this error:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

this is my query:

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM reservation a WHERE a.slotid =:slotid", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteWhereSlotid(Integer slotid);
```

and this is the service:

```
repo.deleteWhereSlotid(reservationSlot.getId());
```

I've also tried:

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM reservation a WHERE a.slotid =:slotid", nativeQuery = true)
Object deleteWhereSlotid(Integer slotid);

//service
Object object= userCourseResRepo.deleteWhereSlotid(reservationSlot.getId());
```

but it failed

Usually I delete rows with `deleteById(id)` which comes with spring

The query works though, I tried it on phpMyadmin console and it worked

Someone know what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know is not the best solution, but you can try to use a query SELECT to find your reservation object and then do this `repo.deleteById(reservation.getId())`

This should allow you to go ahead while you find a better way to do it

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it set up, Spring Data assume you want to perform a query (typically a `SELECT`). For `DELETE` and similar statements that don't return a `ResultSet` you need to provide an additional `@Modifying` annotation.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM reservation a WHERE a.slotid =:slotid", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteWhereSlotid(Integer slotid);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it that way, I believe the query should be:

```
DELETE a FROM reservation a WHERE a.slotid =:slotid
```

I am not particularly sure about the code, however, with Mysql, the case seems to be so when giving an alias to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Param

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM reservation a WHERE a.slotid =:slotid", nativeQuery = true)
Object deleteWhereSlotid(@Param("slotid")Integer slotid);
```

As mentioned above, we use the `@Param` annotation in the method declaration to match parameters defined by name in JPQL/Native query with parameters from the method declaration.